# In a metric space with no isolated points, why is the closure of a discrete set nowhere dense?

Tags: general-topology

Does anyone know why this is true?  I know that the closure of a set in a metric space is the set of points a distance of 0 away from the original set.  Also, a discrete set is one with a neighborhood about any point whose union with the discrete set is that point.

Answer (score 5):

Let $d\colon X \times X \to \mathbf R$ be the metric, and for $x \in X$ and $r > 0$ define
$$
B(x, r) = \{y \in X : d(x, y) < r\}
$$
as usual. Writing $D$ for this discrete subset, suppose we have a non-empty open set $U \subset \overline{D}$. There must be an $a \in U \cap D$; find an $r > 0$ such that $B(a, r)$ is contained in $U$ and contains no other points of $D$. Since there are no isolated points, there is a $y \neq a$ in $B(a, r)$. Can you find a ball around $y$ that doesn't intersect $D$?

Comment: I’m having trouble following the hint at the end. Are you saying that the idea is that a contradiction arrives from constructing a ball around $y$ that doesn’t intersect $D$?

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is the discrete set in question and $x$ is in $D$, let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $\{x\}$ disjoint from $D\setminus\{x\}$.  Then $U$ is also disjoint from $\overline{D\setminus\{x\}}$.  In particular, this means that $\{x\}$ is not in $\overline{D\setminus\{x\}}$, which implies that $\overline{D\setminus\{x\}}=\overline D\setminus\{x\}$.  Thus $U$ is disjoint from $\overline D\setminus\{x\}$.  Since $x$ is not an isolated point, this implies that $U$ is not contained in $\overline D$.  Considering that $U$ could be taken to be any sufficiently small ball centered at $\{x\}$, this shows that $x$ is not in the interior of $\overline D$.

Suppose that $y$ is an element of $\overline D$, and $V$ is a neighborhood of $y$.  Then there is an $x$ in $V\cap D$.  Since $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$, $V$ is not contained in $\overline D$ by the previous paragraph.  Therefore $y$ is not an interior point of $\overline D$.  Since a closed set is nowhere dense if and only if it has empty interior, this shows that $\overline D$ is nowhere dense.