# Can the closure of a discrete set of real numbers have positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Call a set $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ discrete if for each $x\in D$ there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap D=\{x\}$.

**Question:** Is there a discrete subset $D\subseteq [0,1]$ such that its closure has positive Lebesgue measure?

It's known that the closure of a discrete set is nowhere dense (under suitable prerequisites): [In a metric space with no isolated points, why is the closure of a discrete set nowhere dense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59821/in-a-metric-space-with-no-isolated-points-why-is-the-closure-of-a-discrete-set)

However, there are closed nowhere dense sets of positive measure (e.g. fat Cantor sets). But I don't know if these are closures of discrete sets.

Comment: Yes, use a fat Cantor set plus some discrete subset of the complement.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: Let's take the disjoint union of a fat Cantor set and a point. Is this the closure of a discrete set?

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: Can you please describe the discrete set those closure a particular fat Cantor set is? Thanks.

Comment: Let $C$ be any Cantor set in the reals. Then collection of midpoints of the (bounded) complementary intervals of $C$ (or simply choose, in any manner you wish, a point -- or even finitely many points -- from each of these complementary intervals) is a countable discrete set whose closure is $C$ union this countable set. To see this, note that each point of the Cantor set is a limit (one-sided only, in the case of an endpoint) of complementary intervals, so each point of the Cantor set is a limit point of this collection of midpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C\subset {\mathbb R}$ be a Cantor set; let ${\mathcal J}$ denote the set of complementary intervals of $C$. In each complementary interval $I\in {\mathcal J}$ pick one point, $x_I\in I$. Lastly, take $X=\{x_I:  I\in {\mathcal J}\}$. I will leave the rest to you to figure out.